# How to sum within a date range, Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am very conversant with pivot analysis but I do not want to use it for this for my table.

I want to be able to make calculations between a date range. For instance, sales of a particular product from 1st of April to 22nd of June.

Comment: Suggested an edit removing the request to email the answer and tidy up the heading.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT()` for this, the ff. formula in particular:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(dates>=start_date),--(dates<=end_date),--(products=product_name),prices)
```

If you don't want to take the product name into consideration, just remove its corresponding parameter, like so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(dates>=start_date),--(dates<=end_date),prices)
```

Where:
`dates`  refers to the range that contains your **dates** (Column **A** in my example below)
`products`  refers to the range that contains **product names** (Column **B** in my example below)
`prices`  refers to the **range that you'd like to sum up** (Column **C** in my example below)

#### Example:

Suppose I have the ff. table:

[image]

To get the sum of the prices for **Product C** starting from **6/20/2012** to **7/3/2012**, use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(dates>=DATE(2012,6,20)),--(dates<=DATE(2012,7,3)),
            --(products="Product C"),prices)
```

You could also use helper cells to contain the "criteria" for your sum, like the ff:

[image]

The yellow cell above contains the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(dates>=F2),--(dates<=G2),--(products=E2),prices)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would defeat the purpose of an open question and answer forum to email an answer to you...

Two choices:

You need to set up an area of your sheet to construct your query parameters and then use DSUM to sum your data based on those. see: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dsum-function-HP010342460.aspx

OR use SUMIFS function with a series of conditions which must all be logically AND (which should suit you to do product="X", date>1st April, date<22nd June etc)